# Solaris 11 CIFS pam_smb

Tags: solaris, cifs

After installing  a CIFS server on Solaris 11 today I run into a problem after updating

the /etc/pam.d/other to include the line "other password required pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn".

After that I can no longer set any password by using "passwd" cmd.

If I uncomment the new line in /etc/pam.d/other, it is possible to change the password.

I do not find any hints in the Oracle documentation for Solaris 11 regarding this error.

Answer (score 0):

When adding lines to /etc/pam.d/other they must not start with "other", it's already implied in the name of the file. In other words, you need to add this line instead:

```
password required pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn
```

I would also recommend removing the "nowarn" part too, in order to better see what's going on.